# buffer confusion

Tags: c, unix, buffering

Could anyone clarify on the types of buffers used by a program?

For eg:

I have a C program that reads from a stdin to stdout.

What are the buffers involved here? I'm aware that there are 2. 
One provided by the kernel on which a user don't have any control.
One provided with standard streams namely stdout, stdin and stderr. Each having a separate buffer.

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on `linux/unix` then you could more easily understand that there are three streams namely

1.**STDIN:** FILE DESCRIPTOR VALUE `0` (`IN unix`)

2.**STDOUT** :FILE DESCRIPTOR VALUE `1`

3.**STDERR** :FILE DESCRIPTOR VALUE `2`

By default these streams correspond to keyboard and monitor.In unix we can change these streams to read input from file instead of keyboard.To display output on a file rather than monitor using **close(),dup()** system calls.Yes there are 3 buffers involved.To clear the contents of input buffer in c we use **fflush()** function.
If you want to know more about handling these streams in UNIX then let me Know.

Comment: thanks.what are the sizes of these buffers? And how do we change them?

Comment: @John: setvbuf, assuming you're working with FILE* and not raw file descriptors (it seems this is the case).  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setvbuf/

Answer (score 0):

The kernel (or other underlying system) could have any number of layers of buffering, depending on what device is being read from and the details of the kernel implementation; in some systems there is no buffering at that level, with the data being read directly into the userspace buffer.

The stdio library allocates a buffer for stdin; the size is implementation-dependent but you can control the size and even use your own buffer with setvbuf. It also allows you to control whether I/O is fully buffered (as much data is read into the buffer as is available), line buffered (data is is only read until a newline is encountered), or unbuffered. The default is line buffering if the system can determine that the input is a terminal, else fully buffered.

The story is similar for stdout. stderr is by default unbuffered.